# opposite of sub in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to replace the content (or delete it) that does not match with my filter.
I think the perfect description would be an opposite sub. I cannot find anything similar in the docs, and I'm not sure how to invert the regex, but I think a method would probably be the more convenient.

An example of how it would work (I've just changed the words to make it more clear)

```
"bird.cats.dogs".opposite_sub(/(dogs|cats)\.(dogs|cats)/, '') 
#"cats.dogs"
```

I hope it's easy enough to understand.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want to remove what doesn't match the regex, right?

Comment: @DaveNewton I think that ^ Matches beginning of line.

Comment: @Thomas, yes, actually in my case it would be enough to just delete.

Comment: @dioshari I cut and pasted wrong; `?!`

Comment: What is the expected behavior if there are multiple occurrences of `cats.dogs` in string?  What should happen if string is `bird.cats.dogs.dogs.cats.bird`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`String#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) can take a regular expression as its parameter:

```
▶ "bird.cats.dogs"[/(dogs|cats)\.(dogs|cats)/]
#⇒ "cats.dogs"
```

For multiple matches one can use [`String#scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-scan):

```
▶ "bird.cats.dogs.bird.cats.dogs".scan /(?:dogs|cats)\.(?:dogs|cats)/
#⇒ ["cats.dogs", "cats.dogs"]
```

Comment: That's a pretty nice feature!

Comment: You need `join` after it.

Comment: @sawa Updated again: instead of join I got rid of catched groups.

Comment: @sawa  - `sub` replaces only first occurrence, so isn't it okay even if the solution did not work for multiple matches.

Answer (score 3):

So you want to extract the part that matches your regex?

You can use [`String#slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-slice), for example:

```
"bird.cats.dogs".slice(/(dogs|cats)\.(dogs|cats)/)
#=> "cats.dogs"
```

And [`String#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) does the same.

```
"bird.cats.dogs"[/(dogs|cats)\.(dogs|cats)/]
#=> "cats.dogs"
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have a single replacement string because the part of the string that matches the regex might not be at the beginning or end of the string, in which case it's not clear whether the replacement string should precede or follow the matching string. I've therefore written the following with two replacement strings, one for pre-match, the other for post_match. I've made this a method of the `String` class as that's what you've asked for (though I've given the method a less-perfect name :-) )

```
class String
  def replace_non_matching(regex, replace_before, replace_after)
    first, match, last = partition(regex)
    replace_before + match + replace_after
  end
end

r = /(dogs|cats)\.(dogs|cats)/

"birds.cats.dogs.pigs".replace_non_matching(r, "", "")
  #=> "cats.dogs"

"birds.cats.dogs".replace_non_matching(r, "snakes.", ".hens")
  #=> "snakes.cats.dogs.hens" 

"birds.cats.dogs.mice.cats.dogs.bats".replace_non_matching(r, "snakes.", ".hens")
  #=> "snakes.cats.dogs.hens"
```

Regarding the last example, the method could be modified to replace `"birds."`, `".mice."` and `".bats"`, but in that case three replacement strings would be needed. In general, determining in advance the number of replacement strings needed could be problematic.